# Cloning and manipulating nested object using forEach, map, or filter without modifying original object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get a handle on using .map, .filter to clone and modify a big nested JSON object based on a deeply nested property. With the below code, the original `data` and the `filtered` data both end up getting modified, but I'm trying to leave the original `data` intact. What I'm hoping to do is have the deeply nested `concerns` array emptied in the final `filtered` object for a given id, leaving the original `data` as the original complete data set.

```
var data {...};

var dataFilter = function dataBuild(data) {
  var newData = data;

  newData.service_requests = newData.service_requests.map((request) => {
    request.concerns = request.concerns.filter((concern) => {
      return concern.building_id == 2
    });
    return request;
  });

    return newData;
};

var filtered = dataFilter(data);
```

Here's a fiddle with what I'm trying to do with the full object in there.
http://jsbin.com/doyoqinoxo/edit?js,console

Comment: try to call slice() before map.  Arrays and Objects are passed by reference.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "nested JSON object". JSON is text, it's a notation. What you have is an [*object initialiser*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer) or literal.

Comment: Fair enough. I was receiving the data as application/json from the backend, so that's why I referred to it as nested JSON, but good to know the proper terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
var newData = data;
```

you are simply making a second reference to the same object, so:

```
newData.service_requests = ...
```

overwrites the value in *data.service_requests*.

It seems you want *newData* to be a copy of *data*, not a reference to the same object. There are plenty of posts here on how to copy a nested object (a so–called deep copy), e.g. [What is the most efficient way to clone an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object), but please ignore the accepted answer unless you are using jQuery. Use one of the other answers, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/122190/257182).

Comment: Thanks @RobG! I see where I was going wrong now. I guess a lot of the Array.map examples I see out there return data to a new object entirely, so it makes sense as well that I was assigning the map to the first object as well. For what it's worth, I ended up using `var cloneOfA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));` as a quick one liner to do the clone.

Comment: @Pete—that "works" if the object was created from JSON in the first place, but note that JSON doesn't support circular references or functions (and the way it supports dates needs some attention).

Comment: Yeah, I read that in the link you originally posted, but luckily for me, it was JSON in the first place, so I didn't have any functions or references to worry about, and a quick one-liner seemed cleanest given the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

JSIterator .map() creates the new array with the same number of elements or does not change the original array. There might be the problem with referencing if there is object inside the array as it copies the same reference, so, when you are making any changes on the property of the object it will change the original value of the element which holds the same reference.

The solution would be to copy the object, well, `array.Splice()` and `[...array]`(spread Operator) would not help in this case, you can use JavaScript Utility library like [Loadash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11) or just use below mention code:

```
const newList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(orinalArr))
```